# Searching letter by letter in elastic search

Tags: python, elasticsearch

i am using elasticsearch with python as client. I want to query through a list of companies. Say ***Company*** field values are

```
Gokl 
Normn 
Nerth
```

Scenario 1(using elasticsearch-dsl python)

```
s = Search(using=client, index="index-test") \
.query("match", Company="N")
```

So when i put N in query match i don't get Normn or Nerth. I think its probably because of tokenization based on words.

Scenario 2(using elasticsearch-dsl python)

```
s = Search(using=client, index="index-test") \
.query("match", Company="Normn")
```

When i enter Normn i get the output clearly. So how can i make the search active when i enter letter n as in above scenario 1.

Comment: Try using `query_string` instead, as `match` will only work on the full indexed token, not a part of it. The more elaborate way of doing it involves using an edgeNGram token filter at indexing time.

Comment: And please read the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-matching.html), it's really good and has a lot of examples.

Comment: Query string shows the result same as match. Shoild i add anymore filters or mapping

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a prefix search.  I don't know the python syntax but the direct query would look like this:

```
GET index-test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "company": {
        "value": "N"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you need to query companies started with specific letter

In this case you can use this query

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "Company": "n.*"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please read query types from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/full-text-queries.html)

for this case, you can use the code below:

```
s = Search(using=client, index="index-test").\
.query("match_phrase_prefix", Company="N")
```

you can use multi-match query for Company and Another field like this:

```
s = Search(using=client, index="index-test").\
.query("multi_match", query="N", fields=['Company','Another_field'],type='phrase_prefix')
```